# Como habilitar un rango de fechas , a partir de la fecha actual hasta 45 días hábiles atrás con la librería Moment js

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy trabajando en un componente de calendario en js, y necesito saber como habilitar siempre un rango de fechas especifico seleccionables de un calendar con moment JS (hoy, ayer, 7, 30 y 45 días atrás hábiles) , en el calendar tengo la opción de seleccionar una fecha de inicio y otra de fin (max y min), **es decir a partir de la fecha actual hasta 45 días hábiles atrás**, , deshabilitando el resto de los días posteriores o inferiores al requerimiento considerando que si los meses son enero y febrero debería habilitar el ultimo mes del año anterior para cubrir los 45 días seleccionables...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
   value={new Date().toJSON().substring(0,10)}
   min={new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()-1, new 
   Date().getDate()).toJSON().substring(0,10)} max="2022-12-31">
</input>
```

El problema es formatear la fecha al valor requerido por el elemento. Falta la fecha maxima, pero como no pusiste le puse un string con el final de año, pero tal como se pone dinamica la fecha minima, lo puedes hacer con la maxima

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba...
Sí quisiera obtener también los últimos 45 días, solo seria jugar con un valor en Date().getDate()-14) por ejemplo???? es correcto???
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
   value={new Date().toJSON().substring(0,10)}
   min={new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()-1, new 
  ** Date().getDate()-14)**.toJSON().substring(0,10)} max="2022-12-31">
</input>

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado, getDate() devuelve el numero de día, si es menor de 15 y le restas 14 te va a dar un fallo y lo mismo pasa con getMonth(), que no me he dado cuenta. si es enero te va a dar fallo, debes calcular antes que mes y dias es y luego restas un año si es enero o lo que necesites

Comment: yo te aconsejaria la librearia moment js, pero antes dijiste que no querías usar librerías, aun que no se si te referias al datepicker o a las fechas

Comment: Me refiero a las fechas...tengo varias opciones, seleccionar solo el día de ayer, fecha actual, últimos 7 días o últimos 45 días. pero tienes razón no había considerado los mes y los años así como lo mencionas sí es enero...

Comment: Ayuda por favor.....